# Passing tf.data.Dataset using customer generator to multiple input tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to use `tf.data.Dataset` to feed a custom generator to a tensorflow model that takes multiple inputs.  i.e.:
myModel.fit([train_image1,train_image2], train_label)

My customer generator works fine directly as it yields:

```py
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Select the indicies for this batch:
        indices = self.indices[idx * self.batch_size : (idx+1) * self.batch_size]
        
        # Get the data (possibly augmented)
        imgs1, imgs2, labels = self.__data_generation(indices)
        return [imgs1, imgs2], labels # Or yield, doesn't seem to matter.
```

And then:

```py
train_batch_gen = My_Custom_Generator(train_filenames, batch_size)
val_batch_gen = My_Custom_Generator(val_filenames, batch_size)
history = myModel.fit(train_batch_gen, validation_data=val_batch_gen,
                      epochs=2, verbose=1)
```

So this all works fine.

In now moving to `tf.data.Dataset`, I realize that TensorSpec doesn't support lists so that is changed on the generator: I've tried tuples and just return all three arrays from my Custom generator, and used all combinations of signatures with:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(My_Custom_Generator,
                                         output_signature = (
                                         (tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,28,28,1),  dtype=tf.float32),
                                         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,28,28,1), dtype=tf.float32)),
                                         tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,1,) ,dtype=tf.int64) ),                                         
                                         args=(X_train_filenames, batch_size))
myModel.fit(dataset.from_tensors, epochs=2)
```

The above fails in one of two ways depending on returning a tuple (imgs1, imgs2), labels or just all arrays imgs1, imgs2, labels.  The errors are the following.

```
Generator returns imgs1, imgs2, labels (prefetch below):
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
ValueError: Layer "model" expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 28, 28, 1) dtype=float32>]

Generator returns (imgs1, imgs2), labels (prefetch below):
<PrefetchDataset element_spec=((TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None)), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.int64, name=None))>
InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was ((tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.int64), but the yielded element was ([array([[[[0.        ],
```

I'm using tensorflow 2.12.  Also, the following post seemingly found a solution, but that didn't work for me (see above) and the original issue was not including the training target (y==labels):
[ValueError: Layer expects 2 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors when training a CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202194/valueerror-layer-expects-2-inputs-but-it-received-1-input-tensors-when-train?newreg=934644b9ed8e4d918c0ad1361cc73efd)

Any help or example code would be appreciated.  I have searched and searched on this one.  Thanks.